# How to Connect Standalone Stripe account to platform after user authorizes access

Tags: curl, oauth, parse-cloud-code, stripe-connect, stripe.net

When connecting a Stand alone account to a platform in Stripe Connect, there is one more small step to be taken after the user authorizes access. Stripe offeres this code example:

```
 curl https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token \
    -d client_secret=sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \
    -d code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE \
    -d grant_type=authorization_code
```

However, my application runs on Cloud Code, and I would like to make the request from a cloud code function on my parse-server. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution. Hope it helps someone, as it took me a while to get the syntax right from a Cloud Code Function perspective.

```
 Parse.Cloud.define("postRequest", function(request, response){



 Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
     method: 'POST',
     url: 'https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token',
     headers: {
       'Authorization': 'Bearer sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
     },
     body: {
    'code': request.params.code, //the authorization code passed back through the redirect_uri after user authorizes platform
    'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
    'client_secret': 'sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
     },
   }).then(function(httpResponse) {
     console.log(httpResponse);
     response.success(httpResponse.text);
   }, function(err) {
     console.log(err);
     response.error(err);
   });




});
```